# Only variables should be passed by reference -ckeditor -codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckeditor

I try to make text editor using **ckeditor** in my **codeigniter** project. But I always get `Only variables should be passed by reference` error whenever I call method `display_ckeditor` from my view.

This is my error log:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Runtime Notice

Message: Only variables should be passed by reference

Filename: helpers/ckeditor_helper.php

Line Number: 65

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/html/webapp/webappadmin/application/helpers/ckeditor_helper.php
Line: 65
Function: _error_handler

File: /var/www/html/webapp/webappadmin/application/helpers/ckeditor_helper.php
Line: 90
Function: cke_create_instance

File: /var/www/html/webapp/webappadmin/application/views/ubahabout.php
Line: 7
Function: display_ckeditor

File: /var/www/html/webapp/webappadmin/application/controllers/Controll.php
Line: 187
Function: view

File: /var/www/html/webapp/webappadmin/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

Here's my controller that load view:

```
public function ubahabout($id,$tab,$lang){
    //Ckeditor's configuration
    $data['ckeditor'] = array(

        //ID of the textarea that will be replaced
        'id'    =>  'content',
        'path'  =>  'js/ckeditor',

        //Optionnal values
        'config' => array(
            'toolbar'   =>  "Full",     //Using the Full toolbar
            'width'     =>  "550px",    //Setting a custom width
            'height'    =>  '100px',    //Setting a custom height

        ),

        //Replacing styles from the "Styles tool"
        'styles' => array(

            //Creating a new style named "style 1"
            'style 1' => array (
                'name'      =>  'Blue Title',
                'element'   =>  'h2',
                'styles' => array(
                    'color'     =>  'Blue',
                    'font-weight'   =>  'bold'
                )
            ),

            //Creating a new style named "style 2"
            'style 2' => array (
                'name'  =>  'Red Title',
                'element'   =>  'h2',
                'styles' => array(
                    'color'         =>  'Red',
                    'font-weight'       =>  'bold',
                    'text-decoration'   =>  'underline'
                )
            )               
        )
    );
    $data['myid']=$id;
    $data['mylang']=$lang;
    $data['mytab']=$tab;
    $this->load->view('ubahabout',$data);    // <---- ERROR GOES HERE
}
```

and this is my view (ubahabout.php):

```
<div class="main-container">
<?php
$content = $this->contentmodel->load_main_content_by_id($myid);
?>
<textarea name="content" id="content" ><p>Example data</p></textarea>
<?php 
echo display_ckeditor($ckeditor);     // <---- ERROR GOES HERE ?>

</div>
```

The error points out to the line 90 and 65 inside **ckeditor_helper.php**, and I still couldn't figure out what's the problem. Here's those line in ckeditor_helper.php:

line 90: `$return .= cke_create_instance($data);`,

line 65: `if($k !== end(array_keys($data['config']))) {`

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

i also had this problem,
The problem is not your script but the file 'helpers/ckeditor_helper.php'
as shown from the error message.

The lines 65, 108, 116 each have the same issue.
Instead of running the array_keys function inside the 'end()',
assign to a variable first, then use the variable in the function.

**helpers/ckeditor_helper.php**

```
64.         $endkeys = (array_keys($data['config']));
65.         if($k !== end($endkeys)) {
```

```
107.        $endkeys2 = array_keys($v['styles']);
108.        if($k2 !== end($endkeys2)) {
```

```
115.        $endkeys3 = array_keys($data['styles']);
116.        if($k !== end($endkeys3)) {
```

That should take care of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first argument of

```
$this->load->view('ubahabout',$data);
```

is a reference, just try:

```
$a = 'ubahabout';
$this->load->view($a, $data);
```

But not sure, you should also show the definition of `$this->load->view`

Answer (score 0):

> Modify ckeditor_helper.php at system/helper
>
> 64. $endkeys = (array_keys($data['config']));
> 65. if($k !== end($endkeys)) {
> 66. $endkeys2 = array_keys($v['styles']);
> 67. if($k2 !== end($endkeys2)) {
> 68. $endkeys3 = array_keys($data['styles']);
> 69. if($k !== end($endkeys3)) {
>
> 151         $endkeys = array_values($key); 152            if($string !==
>   end($endkeys)) $return .= ",";
>
> 160   $endkeys = array_values($data); 161     if ($key != end($endkeys))
>   $return .= ",";